# Inequality for finite harmonic sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

> For a positive integer $n$ let 
>   $$A(n) = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}+\dots +\frac{1}{2^n - 1}$$
>   Then prove that $A(200) > 100 > A(100)$.

I tried some concepts like AM>GM>HM and some algebraic methods for reducing the series but was unable to solve it.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: You can look up some properties of Harmonic Numbers here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number

Answer (score 1):

Hint. We have that for $k>1$,
$$\frac{1}{2}=2^{k-1}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{k}}<\sum_{j=2^{k-1}}^{2^{k}-1}\frac{1}{j}< 2^{k-1}\cdot \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}=1.$$
Now, note that
$$A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\sum_{j=2^{k-1}}^{2^{k}-1}\frac{1}{j}\right)$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes , thank you

Answer (score 0):

The integral $$ \int _1^{2^n} \frac {1}{x} dx $$ gives an estimate of $$A \approx n \ln 2$$

For $  n=100$ the approximation is $$100 \ln 2 \approx 69.31$$

Which satisfies the given conditions.

For $n=200$ the estimate is $$138.62$$ which verifies the condition as well.

Comment: How did you get that harmonic sum of n terms=  definite integration of lnx ?

Comment: I think that in integration of ln from 1 to 2^n we get 2^n(nln2 -1)+1

Comment: @SmitPatel Thanks for the comment, I just fixed my error. I knew what I wanted to integrate but apparently did not check my typing.

Comment: Why is harmonic sum is approximately equal to integration of 1/X from 1 to 2^n

Comment: @SmitPatel If you check the right and left side numerical approximation to the integral you get the sum. Sketch a graph of $1/x$ and try to approximate the integral using the right side and  the left side approximation with partitions of integer nodes.